# Why Bluetooth needs DBUS way of communication in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, dbus

I am newbie to Android DBUS, recently I was informed that I need to use DBUS to implement Bluetooth in Android, from DBUS documentation I see DBUS is used for communication medium between two applications.

1. In Android apps -apps communication is through intents, if so why do we need DBUS for Bluetooth ?
2. Is that DBUS serves as communication medium for networking (IP) between two apps since it is built over sockets?

Please  correct me if my understanding is wrong, any more information on DBUS along with Bluetooth implementation in Android is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For any application level programming on Android, including Bluetooth, you don't need to worry about D-Bus.

You are right about Android app communication using Intents - Intents are fundamental to Android app development.

Under the covers, Android Intents could be implemented using D-Bus, but it was my understanding that they are not (someone please correct me if I'm wrong).  Either way, you only need to worry about this if you are doing system level Android Bluetooth dev.

Comment: I am not sure if Google Android intents are developed over DBUS but it could also be as you said but I see Bluetooth uses DBUS to communicate with Android **SystemServer** since BLUZ is implemented in C and there should be some mechanism through with BLUZ to communicate therefore it uses DBUS for Bluetooth stack especially, intents could be used if both apps are written in Java since there is stack based on C it could probably using DBUS to achive this!  I could be wrong with my understanding, please correct me

Comment: @RajeshSO, yes, I agree.  Intents are java-to-java, they are not available to native apps, so native code like BlueZ needs a different general IPC: D-Bus.

Comment: recently I learn't intents are higher abstraction of binder IPC mechanism used in Android and they are no way related to DBUS implementation as I thought previously. Binder abstraction is this way Intents -> AIDL -> Binder.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, previous android use bluez for bluetooth implementation. and the bluez implementation rely on dbus. If you are application developer, mostly you don't need to care about the internal implementation of bluetooth, just use the level api and intent